# Can I host Sharepoint Foundation with any of the web Hosting Provider?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I want SP foundation 2013(free version) to be hosted in any Hosting providers like godaddy, Bigrock etc.

Is there any way to do it, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A hosting provider must offer the service, unless they have an Infrastructure as a Service offering, where they just provide you with a Windows Server that you 'own', where you could install it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Apps4Rent is offering the hosting for various SharePoint versions with many options, you can select Shared, Flex Dedicated or dedicated hosting.

I checked they have SharePoint App service for all plans.

[Hosted SharePoint Foundation 2013 Plans](http://www.apps4rent.com/hosted-sharepoint-2013-plans.html)